# Portable C++ build system

Tags: c++, build-process, portability

I'm looking for a good and easy in maintenance portable build system for C++ projects. Main platforms should include Windows (Visual Studio 8+) and Linux (gcc); Cygwin may be an advantage. We're considering two main possibilities: **CMake** and **Boost.Jam**. SCons can be also an option, but I haven't investigated it yet. CMake and Boost.Jam seem to have the following traits:

CMake:

- (+) generates native "makefile" (solution for Windows, project for Eclipse)
- (+) extensions for testing and packaging
- (-) demands a configuration file in *every* project folder
- (-) based on a little too verbose peculiar language

Boost.Jam:

- builds by itself with no intermediate steps
- (-) doesn't generate native solutions/projects
- (+) concise language similar to the classic makefile
- (+) intuitive support for properties like multithreading and static/dynamic library

What are other possibilities and what is really preferable after experience? What build systems can create a solution on the way?

Comment: Qmake: http://doc.trolltech.com/4.2/qmake-manual.html

Comment: @Akusete: post that as an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @Ken Bloom: I didn't have the time to follow through with giving a deep explanation of its pros/cons. I thought at least giving it a mention would encourage someone else to pick it up and run with it.

Comment: [QBS](https://github.com/qbs/qbs)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> (-) demands a configuration file in every project folder

This is not correct, you just need to pass bigger pathes like:

```
add_program(foo src/foo.cpp src/main.cpp)
```

Few notes, about Boost.Jam - first it is not Boost.Jam - bjam on its own quite useless, what you are looking for is Boost.Build which is set of Jam macros that make bjam useful.

Now, I worked with both, and I must admit, Boost.Build is not suitable for any serious projects outside the Boost itself. Need to find library? Can't need to find header? Can't. Need to do something outside of simple build - and you have not idea how to do it as BB documentation... Totally useless and maybe cover 10% of BB. So most of cases you need to ask questions in BB mailing lists and...

So, if you have some complicated project - and you need to make something more then simple compile and link, stay away from Boost.Build.

So if you need to support MSVC I find today CMake as only feasible choice.

I don't tell that CMake is very good system, it has many problems but it is something
mostly suitable for cross platform development (if you need to support MSVC).

And if you don't care about MSVC and happy with MinGW... take a look on autotools as well.

About Scons - it is still less mature them CMake.

Comment: IMHO you should prefer CMake over autotools even if you don't care about MSVC, since it is much easier, and faster. There is a reason, that many (big) open source projects are defecting from autotools to CMake. Which also gives you a huge community of Developers who are familiar with CMake. Additionaly note that CMake has a Company providing support backing it up, which is also quite supportive of open source projects. All that said, CMake is still not perfect.

Comment: Autocrap is more trouble than it's worth. Arcane language to write scripts in (shell and M4), bad documentation, slow runs, and excruciatingly painful to debug (especially for users!) when it does not work as advertised.

Comment: Thanks for more description of CMake, Boost.Build. It seems the correct choice is really CMake (as I do want MSVC support). I'm going to try a little Premake which looks similar to CMake in building, but is based on Lua scripting language.

Comment: @zvrba The documentation of the autotools (autoconf, automake, libtool) is excellent.

Comment: I could argue with this. My mental issue is the fact that CMake generates 4000 lines of makefiles to build a single executable with 1 source file and the fact that CMake uses macros *everywhere*. Boost.Build has horrible docs, but once you learn it, you can do almost anything with it. It also has excellent MSVC support.

Answer (score 14):

This is a bit of a rant, but I'll try to stay objective and only report my experiences:

I have tried CMake on several occasions and I'm close to reaching a point where I will volunteer to either maintain separate project files for each build environment or abuse another language's build system (Ant, NAnt, MSBuild or so) to compile and package my C++ projects.

CMake, as it is:

- It replaces an ugly, but formalized format (Makefile) with an incredibly poorly designed free format (CMakeLists.txt)
- It dumps its configuration, cache and other clutter all across the directories with zero respect for the user's attempts to keep the source tree clean.
- The documentation for CMake is be lacking in most places (for example, try to recursively add a source directory to a target wile excluding certain files for starters)
- The generated IDE projects are incredibly poor (have a well-structured Visual Studio project? CMake will dump all your sources into a single project node)
- The generated IDE projects use absolute paths (so you can't check them into source control -- everyone has to use CMake)
- You can only pick between platforms (eg. x64 and x86) when generating projects / makefiles. CMake won't generate projects supporting multiple platforms even if the IDE would be perfectly fine with this.
- Very little control over how libraries are referenced. There is an array of reference finding methods (so even with the poor control, you can expect no uniformity whatsoever).

My personal view is that even if one wanted to intentionally design the worst cross-platform build system possible, it would be hard to do any worse than CMake.

I don't have any experience with Boost.Build and it may well have equally drastic shortcomings, but the best I can say about CMake is that if your only care is to get some source files built *somehow*, it can get the job done -- albeit with much pain for the developers and the library/application consumers.

Comment: CMake supports out of source builds if I recall correctly, they keep your source tree clean. And you can add multiple projects, they appear as different projects in for example your visual studio solution...

Comment: So, you just dont like CMake. Well, it has it's weaknesses but nearly all buildsystems have them. The documentation is quite good, however, and you should have read it. CMake strongly suggests out of source builds so no clutter. If you want to have files in your IDE grouped, you have to specify this in your CMake file. Very easy. There is a reason why absolute paths are used, also explained in the documentation. I'm running out of characters now, though I'd have more to object....

Comment: You make it sound as if I arbitrarily chose to dislike CMake. I started considering it the build tool of choice and gradually discovered how sloppily it was designed. I also don't agree that other tools have similar weaknesses (nor that it's therefore okay for CMake to be what it is). I have worked with Ant, Maven, NAnt, MSBuild and I started using Boost.Build shortly after posting this - none of them have comparable weaknesses. Compare the build script of any larger project using CMake with one using one of the other mentioned tools and you will know what I mean.

Comment: "It dumps its configuration, cache and other clutter all across the directories with zero respect for the user's attempts to keep the source tree clean." This is completely wrong, simply go out of source and write : cmake /path/to/source and the files get generated there.

Answer (score 9):

I've had some good experiences with premake4: http://industriousone.com/premake

**Update**

I do still like premake, but after working with it awhile, I feel obligated to list some of the shortcomings I've found in it:

- Integrating new toolchains (i.e. preprocessing tools like bison or moc) isn't supported.
- No support for per-file configuration.
- Library finding is inflexible, no support for scripting or version checking.
- Some directives (e.g. configuration) affect following statements, but there's no explicit scope delimitation. This can lead to subtle errors.
- Little support for debugging the configuration, in other words, showing how the configuration is being interpreted, other than examining the generated build scripts or running them.
- For gmake Makefiles at least, there's no option to make paths absolute. This doesn't play well with Vim's quickfix, although it's easy to work around.
- Slow development pace.  New features can be in development for *years*.

Answer (score 5):

I'll follow @Akusete on **QMake**, which is my personal tool of choice for now. Pros and cons are a bit personal too, but here they are:

#### Pros:

- Much conciser script language, compared to CMake;
- Can generate both VS projects and jom-compatible makefiles on Windows;
- Adding toolchains for, say, cross-compilation is quite easy (boils down to a customised `mkspec`, which is written in the same `qmake` language);

#### Cons:

- A bit limited freedom of making arbitrary number of targets. There are some predefined ones, like `app`, `lib` etc., but it's a bit cumbersome to build, say, both shared and static library versions in a single pass, or disable precompiled header for a single source file. It's definitely achievable, but requires some googling and looks dirty;
- Tied to Qt by default (which is easily overridden by addition of `QT -= core gui` line)

#### Overall:

Gets the job done quick on simple-to-medium projects, but still leaves the feeling of *"damn, it could have been done in a simpler way!"* when applied to complex tasks.