# How do you save links with g++/C++?

Tags: c++, opengl, g++, glew

I am writing some OpenGL code, and my links to libraries in /usr/lib is getting quite unwieldly:

```
g++ Application.cpp -lglfw -lGL -lGLEW
```

I don't want to hunt around/can't remember the exact names of the libraries EVERY TIME i want to complile something, so in my project folder I have a file called linkingsNeeded.txt. That file contains that command and nothing else. Is there a way to save the list of linkings so I can just type

```
g++ Application.cpp
```

And not have to deal with manually linking? Say, in the #include section of the CPP file?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_(software)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ Build Systems - What to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12017580/c-build-systems-what-to-use)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Learn to use some [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tool such as [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) or [ninja](https://ninja-build.org/).

You'll then edit your `Makefile` (with *make*); [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14180540/841108) could be inspirational and just build your program by typing `make`. Most source code editors (like [GNU emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/)) or IDEs can be easily configured to run `make` with a single keypress.

Of course you want to [invoke GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) as `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` since you want all warnings and debug info (for the [GDB](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/) debugger).

Read also [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [more about C++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp), perhaps even the [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) quasi C++11 standard.